# How to track down the source of an Eclipse component error?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I'm getting an error on the Spring XML configuration file. Is there a way to track down which Eclipse tool is reporting the error, and try to stop it building?

In my case, I have two suspects:

- Spring IDE (or what I think is known by STS now)
- or my XML IDE (Rinzo XML)

How can I stop either or both trying to "build" and report errors? And in general, how can one figure out which Eclipse component is reporting an error?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your specific question without a similar setup locally. And the answer may depend on anything you have included (including the Eclipse version you are using). I would check the following sources:

- "Error in configuration file": If that means that the problem is listed in the problems view, you have there the information in the column "Type" which gives an indication. See the screenshot how it looks for a checkstyle warning: [image]
- It could as well mean: There is something which is an exception in some plugin. This is shown in your "errors view". So open `Windows > Show View > Error Log` and look if there is an entry corresponding to your error. By double-clicking on the error view, you will see a dialog like the following. If you are lucky, it includes a stack trace that indicates who is responsible. [image]
- You could even start a `Run Configuration` which takes your running eclipse as the source. This will open a running eclipse in a fresh workspace, and you can add breakpoints and do some experimentation there. Of course, you should know what you are doing.
- As a last resort, you could disable some features in your `Run Configuration` for eclipse to see if the problem goes away then.

The last 2 options are only possible if you have PDE (Plugin Development Environment) included in Eclipse. It should be possible to add that to your environment. Depending on the version of Eclipse you are using, you may find a version under [PDE at Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/).

If you want more specific information, you have to add at least the following information:

- Version of Eclipse you are using.
- Set of features you have installed.
- What steps someone has to do to reproduce your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I'm using the latest eclipse Version: 3.7.0  (Build id: I20110613-1736), I've got a lot of features installed: Subclipse, Spring IDE, Mylyn, LogViewer, "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" and many others) I suspect Spring IDE is reporting the errors, and I'm not sure how to tell it not to report errors

Comment: Could you add to your question a more concrete description a) where you see the error b) some information about your project, especially the builders of your project.